# Cloud endpoints authentication from android: Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to access my appengine backend, built using cloud endpoints in python, from my android client - using authentication.

Authentication is working fine from the api explorer.

On the android side, I'm using the credentials/account picker method described here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

But I get the following in the appengine log when accessing from an android client:

"Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user."

And before that there's this warning:

"id_token verification failed: Unable to load pycrypto library.    Can't verify id_token signature. See http://www.pycrypto.org for more information on"

Comment: To help anybody else that might end up here - I fixed the same error (but not Android related - was rolling my own OAuth authentication) with two things: 1. Change App Engine's Google Authentication setting to "Google Accounts API", not "Google Apps Domain", and 2. Use the HTTP header 'Authorization: Bearer <access token here>" instead of the "?access_token=<access token here>" query string parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are accessing GAE app with cloud endpoints from android client, it will be using ID tokens. So if you are getting the warning `Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user` , then you must be seeing some failure in id_token verification and seeing some warning like `id_token verification failed. Checking for oauth token.` Please check if your `endpoints.get_current_user()` method is returning None in this case and then check for any errors in your authentication part.

This post explains [ID tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410013/cloud-endpoints-oauth2-error) in detail and this post explains the [limitations in knowing User_id when using ID tokens and the possible workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661109/google-endpoints-api-chrome-extension-returns-none-for-endpoints-get-current-u/16661765#16661765)

**EDIT:** : Find below the final solution based on Kai Stavginski's suggestions

As suggested, oauth framework warning is seen when there is some error in id_token verification. So as per the modified question, the log has `id_token verification failed: Unable to load pycrypto library` This requires pycrypto library to be added to app.yaml and then id_token failure will be resolved and there will be no oauth related warning.

Comment: you definitely let me in the right direction.. i failed to mention that I was getting this warning: id_token verification failed: Unable to load pycrypto library.    Can't verify id_token signature. Since it kept going after that, I didn't realize that this was the real problem. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: The specific solution was to add the pycrypto library to app.yaml - doh. Want to edit your answer to reflect that?

Comment: nice to know the issue is resolved and i could be of any help. i have updated the answer to include your final solution so that this post could be a useful reference