# How to make a pure JavaScript based Google or Facebook OAuth 2.0 secure to spoofing?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spoofing

I am implementing JavaScript based Google or Facebook OAuth for a client login system, where I hope to use the Access Token and Email Id combination returned from Google/Facebook after successful authentication of the user to create session on the Server. I have a .NET based server application. I am hoping to send this Access Token and Email Id combination using some AJAX methods like $.ajax and creating a session for this email id on the server end.

Now I have a limitation, my server is behind a firewall and it cannot contact Google/Facebook to validate the access token.

One of my colleague pointed me out that as there is no communication between my Server and Google/Facebook, any malicious user can send me user A's email id with any random access token, and I have no way to check the validity of this token whether it actually belongs to User A.

My server is using SSL communication. So, how can I make this scenario secure.

Comment: This video https://developers.google.com/live/shows/800483695-4001 explains how you can do it. It is using Android rather than JavaScript, bu the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you should use a token you can’t validate.  I don’t think your app can be run if you can’t contact IDPs to validate tokens.  It’s a bit surprising, most firewalls let you call *out*, they don’t let others call in.

Answer (score 1):

You could request an ID token as described here [Cloud endpoints oauth2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410013/cloud-endpoints-oauth2-error?rq=1)

This contains a signed user ID and email in a JWT.

This article might help https://support.zendesk.com/entries/23675367-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-

disclaimer: I haven't tried any of this personally. Also, as Tim says, are you sure you can't call out from behind your firewall?

Comment: yes, in my system, firewall rules are opened based on IP addresses only and not based on domain names. The problem in my case is, as Google.com or Facebook.com can have a lot of load balancing IP addresses, I cannot get firewall rules for all the IP address.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why does your firewall restrict **outgoing** IP addresses?

Comment: Its our production server and my organisation is very strict on firewall rules.

Comment: It's perhaps off-topic, but it's more typical to have an http proxy for outbound traffic. You can configure proxy rules to allow/disallow sites, and your firewall would allow all outbound traffic from the proxy. Anyway, have a look at the ID Token as that should work for you.