# Wrong number of segments in token (OAuth Google Api)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, oauth-php

My end goal is to send email to myself via Google Gmail API.

And here is my problem.

When i'm getting my access token an error pops up

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Wrong number of segments in token: '
```

I read here [Cloud endpoints oauth2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410013/cloud-endpoints-oauth2-error) that *"This DOES NOT mean your token was invalid"*, but i'm getting a fatal error that interrupting my script.

My access token looks like this *4/MqiIIl5K4S3D4iiieHshQt5D4M79oo07SbhMn22oe2o.cswa8t9ZuDAfJvIeHux6iLYXpNQmlAI*

If I refresh the page with this token i'd get another error, which is

```
'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Invalid code.'
```

Here is my code

```
<?php

include_once "templates/base.php";
echo pageHeader("Simple API Access");

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../autoload.php');


$client = new Google_Client();


$client_id = '114600397795-j5sn0gvsdrup0s8dcmsj49iojp3m9biu.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'm3Dzankql_rs1OGICsA3Hbtc';
$redirect_uri = 'http://alupa.com/gmail/examples/simple-query.php';

$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
$client->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");

$apiKey = "AIzaSyCWXxrTshKsotxEYNZZCXxdVXhLeku55cw"; 
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  //$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  //header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}else{

$client->setApplicationName("Client_Gmail_Examples");

}


if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
}


?>
<div class="box">
  <div class="request">
<?php
if (isset($authUrl)) {
  echo "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'>Connect Me!</a>";
} else {
  echo "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
  </div>
</div>
```

alupa.com is my local domain and I don't see any problems with that

I'm using original library from google https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: I am having the same problems. The token doesn't have all the data. Did you solve that?

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
```

to:

```
$tuan = $client->getAccessToken();
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken($tuan->id_token);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the scope openid and then you get an id_token as well as the access token. You then use the id token with $client->verifyIdToken